# Eliminar diálogo al escribir código de python

Tags: python, vscode

¿Cómo puedo eliminar este tipo de diálogos molestos que salen al escribir código Python en Visual Studio Code?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Cuadro]

Comment: De que cuadro hablas???

Comment: @gbianchi es una ventana de diálogo que muestra información sobre alguna función, es un "hint".

Comment: me lo imagine.. pero la pregunta es tannnnnn mala... en fin... @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son los diálogos de sugerencia, si deseas desactivarlos ve al menú :

File > Preferences > Settings > Text Editor > Suggestions

Deshabilita la opción "Other"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ojo hay que ver si no tiene un plugin.. vs code es muy sensible...